# Push pop top in stack c ++

Tags: c++, stack

I have an empty stack of integers,and q queries in the following format:
Push x : add x in the top of the stack
Pop: remove the top of the stack
Top: print the top of the stack
Example
Input:
10
Push 5
Top
Push 6
Top
Push 3
Top
Pop
Top
Pop
Top
Output:
5
6
3
6
5
I will put my code in comment because I don't know how to put it here..i know it's extremely wrong but please i need help to improve it

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<int>st;
    int n,a;
    cin>>n;
    string s;
    cin>>s;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s=="push")
        {
            cin>>a;
            st.push(a);
        }

        if(s=="pop")
            st.pop() ;

        if(s=="top")
            cout<<st.top()<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: To add your code to your question, edit it and copy-and-paste your code where indicated.

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    stack<int>st;
    int n,a;
    cin>>n;
    string s;
    cin>>s;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(s=="push"){
          cin>>a;
          st.push(a);
        }
        if(s=="pop")
           st.pop() ;
        if(s=="top")
           cout<<st.top()<<endl;
    }
}

Comment: Sir i tried it but it's not work

Comment: It says Oops! Your answer couldn't be submitted because:

Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Comment: You also never asked an actual specific *question*. And fyi, `std::string` requires including `<string>`, which what little code we *can* make out never includes.

Comment: What is not understood in the question?

Comment: @paul sanders thanks for edit

Comment: *What question*. "I need help to improve it" isn't question. Your posted question should include a description of what your code is intended to do, what it seems to be doing, how those things differ, any debugging efforts you've made thus far, and what those efforts have yielded thus far. Related, string comparison is case  sensitive, so "Pop" will never equal "pop", for example,. if we are to believe the sample input data is accurate.

Comment: I need my code to check if s equql to push then add x in the stack else if x equal to pop then remove the top of the stack and if s equql to top then print the top of the stack but it doesn't make that it doesn't print anything..and I don't know why?!

Comment: @sondosToney That information belongs [**in your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63662959/edit)

Comment: @whozeCraig yea sir i understand that my question wasn't specific

Comment: Is each command presented on a separate *line* ? I.e. First line: the count of commands, next line: `Push 5` , next line: `Top` , next line: `Push 6`, etc. ?

Comment: @whozcraig yes sir

Comment: @sondosToney You still have not edited your question to include debugging details (input, expected output, and actual output).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the purpose of the `for` loop, as coded.  Instead, (and taking ajourney's answer on board), I would do:

```
int main()
{
    stack<int>st;

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        string s;
        cin >> s;

        if(s=="push")
        {
            int a;
            cin>>a;
            st.push(a);
        }

        if(s=="pop")
        {
            if (!st.empty ())
                st.pop() ;
            else
                cout << "Stack is empty\n";
        }

        if(s=="top")
        {
            if (!st.empty ())
                cout<<st.top()<<endl;
            else
                cout << "Stack is empty\n";
        }

        if(s=="quit")
            break;
    }
}
```

Also, I have moved the declarations of `s` and `a` to be as close as possible to the point of use.

Comment: sandera but now the code won't stop i want it to stop after doing q queries

Comment: @sondosToney Why?  Isn't it better if it stops when the user tells it to?

Comment: do you have any account in social media as Facebook or Instagram so i can communicate with you please?

Comment: @sondosToney No.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answering ..i edit some of it and now it's the best answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to check one more condition that whether the stack is empty or not, like `if(s=="pop" && s.empty() == false)` , then only you can pop. Similar thing with top. Otherwise code will throw run time error when the stack is empty. Also, try using `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Apart from it, since there are q queries as per you question, you need to take `cin>>s` inside `for` loop.

Comment: _try using #include<bits/stdc++.h>_ That is non-portable, non-standard, and pulls in every header in the standard library unnecessarily.

Comment: Then you can leave it, if it is not portable.